# How to check if current page is the default page of the current site using jsom or REST?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, jsom, default

In SP2013, how can I check if the current page is the default page of the current site using javascript object model or REST api?

Thanks

Comment: which template are you using?

Comment: both publishing and team site.

Comment: I used a powershell script some time ago, that iterates throug all the Web's RootFolder files, and maybe if you compare the names you can achieve what you need.. I know that's not exactly what you want because you need this to work using the REST api, but maybe you find it useful: $site = Get-SPSite 'http://yoursite/'
$web = $site.RootWeb
foreach($file in $web.RootFolder.Files){
write-host $file.Name -ForegroundColor Magenta
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first get the current page from `_spPageContextInfo`

```
var currentPage = _spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath
```

Now make a GET request in following end-point to get default or welcome page

```
_api/Web/RootFolder/WelcomePage
```

After getting the response, check if both are same.

**PS:** It works in team & publishing site both.

## Sample code is jQuery & REST API

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("SP.js", "SP.ClientContext", function() {
    var currentPage = _spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/RootFolder/WelcomePage",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (currentPage.indexOf(data.d.WelcomePage) > -1) {
                console.log("Current page is default");
            } else {
                console.log("Current page is not default");
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
});
```

`SP.SOD.executeFunc` is important, you are executing code on publishing site

Comment: This is for team site? Is there one for publishing site?

Comment: Did you try in publishing site?

Comment: It works in team and publishing site both. @omega

Comment: Post is a little old, but thought I would comment that if you're working in SPO, there's a _spPageContextInfo.isWebWelcomePage property. Might be worth checking if the latest SP 2013/2016 OnPrem code has it before going REST call.